# Google translate api for php

Tags: php, google-translate

I'm having a ton of trouble getting this to work. Mainly i'm having a hard time getting started.

I used the free google translate before and all I had to do was copy and paste a script and google generated to translate my entire website.

Now switched over to google translate api so I can customize some of translations.  But the documentation is saying I have to do something like

```
 $text = 'this is text';
 $translate = googleTranslate($text) //just making this up, but its something similar
```

I don't wanna instantiate a $text variable for every single page and word i need to translate. I just want it to scan the page and translate it like it did with the free google translate.

How am I suppose to get started??

And how do I customize translations?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started The docs are really simple and clear. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: It all seems very manual.  Like do I have to build the dropdown for language selection myself? And if I want to translate an entire html page, do I have somehow get all the strings with the html tags and put it in a variable before I can have it translated? Just seems like a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

Being designed for instant translation, the Google Translation API (previously named Translate API) may not be best suited for customizing translations. As a separate product available as part of the Google apps for Business, the Google [Translator Toolkit](https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/?hl=en#topic=6306364) lists HTML file formats as being [supported](https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/answer/6306382?hl=en&ref_topic=6306365) and offers several [features](https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/answer/6306366?hl=en&ref_topic=6306364) that may help customizing your translations.

As for the Translation API, it is designed to translate text strings in either plain-text or HTML format. Therefore, mapping the different sections of your website, is necessary in order to send the API only the desired text to be translated. Still, you may want to have a look at the Google Translate Client Library’s “translateBatch” [method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.20.1/translate/translateclient?method=translateBatch) allowing to translate multiple strings from one language to another.

Answer (score 0):

you must to use the google API, check this link https://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/

hope i help you.